# How to set cURL default --insecure option?

Tags: curl, command-line

I have to execute a command which executes a few other set of commands automatically. One of those commands is:

`curl -k https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.5.1/protoc-3.5.1-linux-x86_64.zip`

But I want this command to run with an `--insecure` flag so that the verification of curl's certificate doesn't take place as I'm behind a corporate proxy.

I understand that I need to edit the `.curlrc` file to add the `--insecure` option.

I checked my $HOME directory, and such a file doesn't exist. Should a create a new .curlrc file? What should be its content to start with? How does a sample .curlrc file look like? What all are its contents?

I found this link: [Sample .curlrc file](https://gist.github.com/v1m/f1d4751883f19c916515). However, this doesn't explain things clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I found that you can just create the $HOME/.curlrc file yourself and it can just contain the `-k` or `--insecure` flag without anything else in the file. I have to do this programmatically, so I run this line of code before running the curls:

`echo "-k" > ~/.curlrc`